# serialising an image using JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, image, windows-phone-8

I have a viewmodel which have an image. When i serialize the view model it doesn't convert the object into anything. So when i deserialize I couldn't get the correct view model.

viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel(string imageUrl)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageUrl))
        {
            IsImageLoading = true;
            _img = new BitmapImage();
            _img.ImageOpened += (s, e) => { IsImageLoading = false; };
            _img.DownloadProgress += (s, e) => { DownloadProgress = e.Progress; };
            _img.ImageFailed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    IsImageLoading = false;
                    _img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Images/fwakes.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
                };
            _img.UriSource = new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
    }
    .....

    BitmapImage _img;

    public BitmapImage Image 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _img;
        }
    }
}
```

Serialising the objects into storage:

```
public bool SaveItems(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> source)
    {
        string jsonContents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source, Formatting.Indented);
```

So how can i serialize correctly so that data binding for image doesn't trouble.

The aim of my project is that when I have internet I would download all the viewmodel with images and when there isn't internet I would deserialize the viewmodel to get images and bind them. What is the effective way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't serialize the image, you save it in the isolated storage and then you serialize the *path* to the image.

See http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage---read-and-save-images for saving/loading images.

Comment: I have a viewmodel with many properties. An image is also a property to the viewmodel. So i would serialize everything at once. You mean to say that there is no way to serialize the images using JsonConvert?

Comment: Images can be serialized, but don't do that. They are binary data and belong in the file system. And BitmapImage is **not** serializable.

Comment: If he really wants to serialize the image, can do so by converting it to a base 64 data string. But i don't see the point of doing so.

Comment: @Dirnthelord That would take a lot of space for nothing.

Comment: @ToniPetrina That is a great advice but I am getting an error for reading the image from the isostorage.
Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.  at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)

Comment: @ToniPetrina Exactly my point.

@Max `Image i = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");`

Comment: @Dirnthelord How can i use Image.FromFile("..")?? I have stored the image in isolated storage as suggested. Or if I have to do like u said , how can i retrieve the image? What is that fromfile function does? where do you want me to retrieve?

Comment: +1, I also see no point in serializing Image when you use it from Storage - in both cases it is stored on disk. But serializing a path is a lot easier and faster.

Comment: @Max is it stored in the same disk as the system you are developing? then you can just give the full/relative path to the image.

Comment: @Dirnthelord This is windows phone for which I am developing and not wpf. It is not supported. And Romasz I had to save the image because I couldnt serialize. I know that there is no point in saving again to storage. But saving the image caused an error as I said. I would open a new question for that.